# still frame camera solve

Tags: tracking

I've found a number of how-tos for solving video but I'm just looking to put an element in a photo and can't seem to find a how-to for that.  Is it possible in blender to do a camera solve with a still image?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I get what you are asking . . . there isn't any parallax or rate of change ratios that can be compared to a constant like that. You shouldn't need it

Comment: In cinema 4d they have a camera calibrator tag where you can load an image for the camera and then draw lines that represent the x, y and z axis.  once you have a few lines drawn for each axis that follows lines in the photo you can select 2 lines and use them as a pin which means the world origin.  Once all of that is done, c4d can solve the camera.  It's all based on a single image, not a video.  I'm just wondering if you can do the same in blender.  Here's a video of it in c4d - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIt6jKXEITc

Comment: not using the tracker, but there is a great (free) [addon](http://stuffmatic.com/blam-blender-camera-calibration-toolkit/) that will help you here (sounds like it works the same as cinema 4d).

Comment: @David your recommendation is awesome, this should be an answer. (including the github link https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam )

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67844/is-there-any-way-to-calculate-camera-focal-length-and-sensor-size-from-a-single

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an addon called **BLAM: Camera Calibration Toolkit** it can be used to match geometry to still images.

It uses the grease pencil to determine the perspective and focal length, and has tools for geometry reconstruction.

see http://stuffmatic.com/blam-blender-camera-calibration-toolkit/
It can be downloaded here: http://stuffmatic.github.io/

**UPDATE:** Blam is no longer mantained and has been replaced by fspy:

https://fspy.io/

For a detailed post on how to use blam and Fspy read: **[How can I recreate geometry using a photograph?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102697/how-can-i-recreate-geometry-using-a-photograph)**