# Background Image Geometry

Tags: image

I've decided to embark on my first background image model and I'm off to a rough start.

My Blender geometry doesn't line up nicely with the image geometry.

Everything is fine with the rotation but when overlaying a cube, things don't line up.

The left side of the cube is pretty much perfect but the right side won't play nice.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: This is an obvious candidate for the [Blam](https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam) add-on

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no direct answer, you just have to do it (well) or somebody else has to do it. Here are some values which affect alignment of your geometry: *Lens distortion, Focal Length and Sensor Size, Camera Position and Rotation, Focal Shift and Image Cropping*. If you adjust all these parameters correctly it should almost line up. But camera position can also be calculated by the BLAM add-on or the internal Camera Tracking solver.

Comment: Matching the perspective of an existing image is not as straightforward as you think. Read these related links: [How can I recreate the floor using a photograph?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102697/how-can-i-recreate-the-floor-using-a-photograph/102750#102750) and [How do I align my grid to background footage?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40308/how-do-i-align-my-grid-to-background-footage/40330#40330)