# How to lock the background image to the camera view in 2.8?

Tags: image

In previous versions of blender you could have the background image be always lined up with the camera, so it was possible to align the 3D view to match with the perspective of a reference image. [Example from this link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40308/how-do-i-align-my-grid-to-background-footage/40330#40330)

[image]

in 2.8

[image]

Is there a setting I don't know to do this? I really would love to avoid using constraints on the empty.

Comment: See point 2 in my answer

Comment: So, @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I'm sorry I just don't get it. How do I do what is shown on the first gif? where the camera moves, but the background image stays put?

Comment: You have to use the new Camera background image feature in 2.8. The image is added directly on a camera object instead of an empty. Select a camera object and choose it from the object data tab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91465/discussion-between-cegaton-and-duarte-farrajota-ramos).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the camera selected, find the camera settings in the Properties window.

Enable Camera background.

Select the image.

[image]

The image will now show when using camera view.

[image]

Comment: You sir, made my day! Thank you :)

Comment: Also ensure "Show Overlay" is turned on for this Camera BG to show up on 3D View. It does not seem to render however...

Comment: This so does not work for me in 2.82. I set up everything like you said but I see no image anywhere :(