# Render scene where camera has background image (Blender 2.8)

Tags: rendering, camera

After a few hours playing with Blender I was able to:

1. Figure out how to add a background image reference
2. Match the camera position to my bg image using fSpy and fSpy addon for Blender 2.8
3. Model a simple wood deck

[image: Blender environment]

However, I can't get to render the whole thing including the image that is already correctly positioned.

I went through articles that will tell you how to add an image as a background, but not with it as a background for the camera.

Is there a way that I can render this with the setup I already have?

I'm using Blender 2.8.

Here's what I see in the rendering view:

[image: No background in render]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110532/cannot-find-background-images-feature-in-blender-2-8 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5802/how-to-composite-in-a-background-picture

Comment: Read: [how to lock the backgound image to the camera view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135145/how-to-lock-the-background-image-to-the-camera-view-in-2-8/135150#135150) and [Cycles not rendering image used as background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38452/cycles-not-rendering-image-or-movie-clip-used-as-background-in-the-viewport/38464#38464)

Comment: I have the same exact problem (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154792/how-to-render-a-background-image-in-2-8). @DuarteFarrajotaRamos and @ cegaton Only the last reference is about rendering, all the others are about the 3D View. However, that one gives two solutions (Compositing and World Background).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add geometry on top of your background image, in order to render.

Once you add geometry, subdivide everything and then Press U >> Project from View

After that, add a material to the geometry and inside this one, add your image.

Finally, render.

[image]

Good Luck