# How to render a background image in 2.8?

Tags: rendering, image

I'm trying to "add" an 3D object onto a photo. I have added the photo to the scene in three ways so far, but none of them render (eevee):

1. Camera > Background Images
2. Empty
   a. Add > Empty > Image (Empty gets added to current Collection)
   b. Add > Image > Backround (Empty gets added to Scene Collection)

These all show up in the 3D View and I was able to align the camera and the object so its perspective matches the scene in the photograph. But when I Render the scene, I only see the object, not the background image.

For the latter, it's simple: **Empties are not rendered** at all.
There are few questions about this, since 2.8 has changed how it handles background images. The most popular seems this one (it includes references to others):

- [How do I set a background image while I am editing?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing#314)

But I seem not to be able to find a method to have the background image render.

Another method might be to use the *Compositor* (Nodes) to *Mix* or *Alpha Over* an *Image* with the *Render Layers*. But this does not give the same alignment as achieved with the background image (also this requires that the World background does not get rendered (Alpha channel); for Eevee, this can be achieved by checking *Film>Transparent*).

What other options are there?

Docs:

- https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/More_Features#Image_Objects
- https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/empties.html
- https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cameras.html#background-images

Answer (score 3):

To do this without making it the background of your whole scene like handle does, I reccomend the images as planes addon.

This makes your image displayed on a mesh plane, meaning it will show up as desired in the render.

First enable it in the preferences:
[image: here]

Then just add an image as a plane from the add menu:
[image: add menu]

And then it should show up in your scene as you want.

Answer (score 0):

From https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38464/33447:

The alternative is to set the World background:

[image]