# How do I export my work to be used in After Effects

Tags: rendering, export, compositing-nodes

Here is a screenshot of my work:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dX1J.jpg

I would like to render the 3D model with its textures on, and make it look like it is part of the original shot. How on earth do I do that? I don't know where to begin as I want the angles and perspective to line up with the angles of the original video.

Thank you,
and I apologise for the (probably) newbie question :-)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102697/how-can-i-recreate-the-floor-using-a-photograph/102750#102750 and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67844/is-there-any-way-to-calculate-camera-focal-length-and-sensor-size-from-a-single/110679#110679 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40308/how-do-i-align-my-grid-to-background-footage/40330#40330