# Matching up perspective to background image

Tags: camera

I'm trying to match up the perspective of a camera to a background image. The purpose is to render furniture to composite into the image. Does anyone know of a good way to line up the plane so it the same perspective as the floor? I've already set the blender camera to be the same focal length. I know if I mess with the position and angle long enough I will get it but any ideas on how to speed up the process up would be much appreciated.

-Thanks

[image: perspective image match example]

[Blender File if you'd like to try it yourself](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O1LFLulpOyv7uNJsv9UkYiwfiAMebNRq/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please pack the textures into your .blend file and then post it again (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39257/packing-texture-files-in-a-single-blend-file).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I align my grid to background footage?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40308/how-do-i-align-my-grid-to-background-footage/40330#40330)

Comment: See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33625/still-frame-camera-solve/33628#33628

Comment: There's an add-on called BLAM that helps to do what you want

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're having trouble is that your photo camera wasn't straight.  I can tell because the far corner isn't perfectly vertical.  It's VERY easy to fix this particular image:

1. go to the Camera view
2. Hit 'R' (Rotate)
3. Type -4.2

Pretty darn close when you move it back to the corner.  You can tweak it a little either direction to make it more exact. Caveat is that I had to guess a bit because that gray floor was in the way since I just downloaded your example image.

[image]